# catkin export definitions

Tags: pcl, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

packages that use PCL need to add those 2 lines in the CMakeLists:

```
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Is there an option to pass those flags and apply them automatically to all packages that use PCL indirectly, by depending on a package that uses PCL?

e.g. let's a package A that uses PCL and so it has the 2 lines above in its CMakeLists, and a package B that uses package A, but does not use PCL directly. It's CMakeLists thus does not include those 2 lines.

I does not seem practical to request a package developer to check all the packages depended upon and check what flags they require... So I bet there is a solution...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/123646/catkin-export-definitions/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2014-01-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Based on dirk-thomas' answer, here is the complete solution for reference:

1- I created A/cmake/A-extras.cmake.in with the following content:

```
# force automatic escaping of preprocessor definitions
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0005 NEW)

add_definitions(@PCL_DEFINITIONS@)
link_directories(@PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS@)

cmake_policy(POP)
```

2- I modified A's CMakeLists file as follow:

2.1- I added

```
CFG_EXTRAS A-extras.cmake
```

to the catkin_package() macro

2.2- I added

```
include(${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/share/${PROJECT_NAME}/cmake/A-extras.cmake)
```

to A's CMakeLists.txt so that the definitions are used to build A itself

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-01-28**:
The last bit (2.2) should not be necessary: the cmake snippets exported in catkin_package(.. CFG_EXTRAS ..) are automatically included byt the dependent package. Unless of course you are including A-extras.cmake in A itself as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your package can create a CMake extra file. That file is registered with `catkin_package(CFG_EXTRAS ...)` and will be included every time your package is `find_packaged()` by others.

As an example you can look at: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/hydro-devel/tools/rosconsole/CMakeLists.txt#L47 and https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/hydro-devel/tools/rosconsole/cmake/rosconsole-extras.cmake.in

May be the API doc will also help what you can actually pass as an argument and what kind of templates you can use: http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-package

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2